# Angular $routeProvider: Why does CRUD new route not work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm building an Angular app with RESTful CRUD actions. Almost everything is working except for the `/users/new` route ~ it displays the *show* view instead of *new* view specified in $routeProvider. However, `'/new'` does work. I'm not getting any feedback in the js console. Any ideas or examples I should read?

```
App.config [
  '$routeProvider'
  '$locationProvider'

  ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, config) ->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
      ).when('/users',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/index.html'
        controller: 'UserIndexCtrl'
      ).when('/users/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/show.html'
        controller: 'UserShowCtrl'
      ).when('/users/:id/edit',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/edit.html'
        controller: 'UserEditCtrl'
      # why does following not work:
      ).when('/users/new',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/new.html'
        controller: 'UserNewCtrl'
      # but this does:
      ).when('/new',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/new.html'
        controller: 'UserNewCtrl'
      ).otherwise(redirectTo: '/')
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $routeProvider try to test url pattern defined from TOP to BOTTOM.
So the URL pattern `/users/new` match `/users/:id` defined 3rd before `/users/new` defined 5th.

If you define `/users/new` before `/users/:id`, I expect that it would work properly.

The code should be like below.

```
App.config [
  '$routeProvider'
  '$locationProvider'

  ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, config) ->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
      ).when('/users',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/index.html'
        controller: 'UserIndexCtrl'
      # you should write it before '/users/:id'
      ).when('/users/new',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/new.html'
        controller: 'UserNewCtrl'
      ).when('/users/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/show.html'
        controller: 'UserShowCtrl'
      ).when('/users/:id/edit',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/edit.html'
        controller: 'UserEditCtrl'
      ).when('/new',
        templateUrl: 'partials/users/new.html'
        controller: 'UserNewCtrl'
      ).otherwise(redirectTo: '/')
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works! Now I know that the route order matters.