# RouteProvider is not loading newly added view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I am facing issue while adding new route in $routeProvider. Here is my app:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'ngCookies',
'home',
'signIn',
'register',
```

]);

Here is my routeProvider

```
app.config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 
function ($provide, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'App/Home',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
});

$routeProvider.when('/register', {
    templateUrl: 'App/Register',
    controller: 'registerCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/signin/:message?', {
    templateUrl: 'App/SignIn',
    controller: 'signInCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/assetdetail', {
    templateUrl: 'App/AssetDetail',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});    
}]);
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('home', [])
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $filter,$route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.getAssetDetail = function () {

        $location.path('/assetdetail');
        $location.reload();
    };
```

I am trying to load new view on the getAssetDetail function call from my existing view, but on function call URL changes but new View does not load. 
My new view is in same directory where existing views are. I have also tried to reordering the routes as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478524/3266029) answer but not worked. Please give me some ideas to resolve this issue.

Comment: create some plunker pls

Comment: When I am assigning existing view like 'App/Register' to new route  /assetdetail' then it works but for my newly created view it does not work, strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `$location.reload();`
don't know if it is related to the problem, but you have the same controller for `home` and `assetdetail`

Comment: create a plunker, it is hard to say what is your problem. what devtools says?

Comment: Firebug tells that navigation path is loaded to the browser but my view remains unchanged !

Comment: if you don't have plunker, upload the project sample. I will help you with debugging

Comment: Ok, let me create plunker!

Comment: i am sure, the problem is due to the argument to $location.path('/assetdetail'); what url does it take you to, finally? and can you check '$baseurl/assetdetail' is working properly. It is not a good practice to prepend the url string argument to $routeProvider.when with '/' since browser may assume that the given url string is the complete url.